# PS3 controllers won't sync - nothing works, help!

Tags: ps3, controllers

Never had any issues with my PS3, worked flawlessy for years. And now, out of the blue, I come back from a vacation and my controllers won't sync. First it started by not being able to turn on the PS3 from the controller (with it turned on, I could sync), but now it won't sync at all. Both controllers, nada, zip, silch.

I searched online for various methods:

1. Reset (did it multiple times)
2. Reset, plug in, unplug, P button (in various orders)
3. Safe mode: repair database
4. Safe mode: repair filesystem

It still works plugged-in to the console, but I'm afraid even this will stop working soon and it will render my PS3 useless.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You say that at first, you could not turn on the console, and eventually, this lead to complete wireless inability.

This sounds like a part had gradually failed. I would be looking towards the controller. Test the controller's connection to another PlayStation, and if the problem persists, replace the controller.

If the problem does not persist, or you are in fact experiencing the same issue at the same time on multiple controllers, this could easily be a failure of the PlayStation's Bluetooth component. Test a separate controller, if you can, to confirm. Alternatively, send the PlayStation back to Sony for repair, or replace the PlayStation.

I would assume the same Bluetooth connection is also behind the inherited support reported for a standard Bluetooth headset. If you have one available, this type of device might also be worth testing in order to narrow down the source of the fault.